# Why does Windows Vista UI insist on staying in Swedish?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, user-interface

I just changed the display language on Windows Vista Ultimate from the native Swedish to English. It logged me out and after logging back in everything seemed to be translated to English and I was happy. But then I did a Windows Update search and the language was Swedish. But if I right-click on the address bar or the search field I get context menu in English. As you can see from the screenshot below.

[image: windows update in swedish and english]

However, if I click the link "System and Maintenance" in the address bar of this same window it takes me to that page and everything is in English. See the screenshot below.

[image]

What is this?... bad translation work from Microsoft? Bad interface/translations design? Do I need to flush some redundant cache memory or something? I mean like with some web pages that sometimes need a cache flush in order to display properly?

Is there a solution to this? I mean besides getting a Windows Vista RTM disc with native English support or buying a new copy of Windows 8 in English? Paying extra for the Ultimate edition of Vista just to be able to switch display language seems pointless and a waste of money if it doesn't do a decent job of translating the interface.

**Update:**
Note that I have the fully localized Swedish version of Windows Vista. It's not a Swedish MUI language pack on top of an English version of Windows Vista! I want the opposite of that.

In the image below you can see the language pack removal dialog in Vista. If I mark Swedish from the list, you can see that it says I can't remove it.

[image: regional and language options in vista]

[image: language pack removal dialog in vista]

> The language can't be selected because it is the system language
>   (default language of the user interface).

But I can select English for removal. Because this is the language pack I installed through Windows Update, as part of the Vista Ultimate Extra program.

[image: windows update optional language packs]

Comment: if need wait test ...

Answer (score 1):

Download 64-bit Vista SP2 MUI Language Pack

[Swedish language 64-bit](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/06/lp-sv-se_3acc7b5efb8e4a946bf2d6bf67305f39a6ce6002.exe)

Download 32-bit Vista SP2 MUI Language Pack

[Swedish language 32-bit](http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/updt/2009/06/lp-sv-se_656141ec6bc0b64b2ae8e3afd11e9e26b26d1e87.exe)

Control Panel\Regional and Language Options\Keyboards and Languages tab\Install/uninstall languages

[image: Vista Install/uninstall languages]

Select install language

[image: Select install language]

[Understanding Language Packs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766472%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[image: Language Pack Types]

Language Pack Types:

1. Fully localized language pack
   Contains 100 percent of the resources for a language and locale.
2. Partially localized language pack
   Contains 100 percent of the resources for a language and locale, but not all of the resources are localized in the language pack. Partially localized languages are installed on top of a fully localized language pack. When a partially localized language pack is installed on a fully localized language pack, the fully localized language pack is known as a base language pack. For example, Arabic (Saudi Arabia) is a partially localized language pack and contains 80 percent of the language resources localized in Arabic. The remaining 20 percent of the language resources can be in either English or French. Both English and French are fully localized, base language packs.
3. Language Interface Pack (LIP)
   A partially localized language pack that includes less than 100 percent of the localized resources. LIPs can be installed only on top of a fully localized language pack. LIPs can also be installed on a partially localized language. The language that a LIP is installed to is called the parent language. The parent language can be in either a fully localized language pack or a partially localized language pack.
   The procedures for adding language packs and specifying language settings are the same for LIPs.
   The following figure shows the different types of language packs and language pack configurations.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that third link points to a redistributable package for Service Pack 2 for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista. I am running Windows Vista with integrated SP2. So I don't need that.

Comment: It's actually Control Panel, then "Clock, Language, and Region", and then "Regional and Language Options".

Comment: @Sammy Yes, thank you, if you wish can edit my post.

Comment: Sure, you can do that if you want. But why do you seem to be under the impression that I need Swedish language pack? It is in Swedish already. I want it in English. So I would need English language pack, not Swedish. My Windows is fully localized to Swedish. So I am going from Swedish to English. Not the other way around.

Comment: How many languages do you have installed? Why does it say "the total number of languages allowed on this computer has been reached" in one of you dialog boxes?

Comment: I believe you can install as many language packs as you like, or as many as there are readily available. Aside from Swedish which is my system language I have installed English, and I have 33 more languages available. So that puts the maximum number of languages to 34, unless there is some other restriction in Windows that don't allow for more than one language pack to be used at a time.

Comment: Correction: to be installed at a time.